# File browsing is not working Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to browse `XLS` file and processing.
First time I am browsing file and processing ,having some errors in file its showing.
I am clearing errors and selected file .Re-corrected the error file.
I am trying to browse re=corrected file (same file whatever I browse first time),but its not working.Its not reading file in Chrome.

This functionality is working fine in **Mozilla**.

```
<input type="button" value="browse"/>
<input type="file" id="manifestFileId" name="manifestFile" class="file_input_hidden createPageBrowseButton"  onchange="alertFilename()"/>
<input type="button" class="clearFileInput" id="resetform" name = "reset" value="clear" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To reload the file you first need to clear the existing value.

```
document.getElementById('manifestFileId').value = null;
```

After this, you should be able to reselect the updated file.

Comment: I cleared existing file after that i recorrected file and browsing

Comment: it has something to do with chrome permissions probably